# how to show spinner values from top?

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, arraylist, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

i am creating an android app in which i want to show countries and i did it successfully my problem is when i click on spinner it show country values from the bottom and i want to show countries from the top of the spinner here is my code how i can achieve this task??

```
MySpinnerAdapter adapter_country = new MySpinnerAdapter(SignUp.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, countryname);
            adapter_country.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinner_country.setAdapter(adapter_country);
            spinner_country.setSelection(countryname.size() - 1);
```

Comment: remove spinner_country.setSelection(countryname.size() - 1); from your code.

Comment: if i remove it index 0 value will be selected and i don't want any value selected

Comment: Add an extra item in position 0 saying "Select country..."

Comment: you can set 0 for that, spinner_country.setSelection(0);

Answer (score 0):

Add blank value in First index in your **countryname** ArrayList and then set it to spinner.

also set :

```
spinner_country.setSelection(0);
```

So, Spinner default selection will be blank...